# What causes an unupvote and why would I get one?

Tags: discussion, support, editing, reputation, etiquette

I looked at my reputation today and noticed something odd, an 'unupvote' on my answer to this [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/189323/which-is-the-right-screws-to-use-to-mount-ikea-pegboard-to-studs-for-heavy-weigh/189326#189326). This occurred after my answer was edited for a very minor spelling issue.

I've never heard of this and as far as I know, one can not change their vote after placing it so it's not the unclicking of an up vote. Because there is no explanation, my answer is on point and as far as I know has no issues, and I can't find any information on unupvote, I feel like I did something 'wrong' or it's a punishment? If I did something, I would like to know what it is so I can correct it

What makes this occur? Is there something I can do to improve my answers so I am not unupvoted?

[image]
[image]

Comment: See also [this Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194483/244695)

Comment: Thank you. This didn't show up for me when I searched with "unupvote' and other key words. I'm still very confused about the why. I mean it was the only answer, the change was very minor, and if a good edit, it IMPROVED the post. So I just don't understand the unupvote, which is in effect a I've changed my mind and it's now a down vote, and if I did I know I could have the choice to improve on the issue. I think that there isn't a way for me to know and I'll just have to let it go as one of those things that people do, for reasons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An 'unupvote' is when someone who previously upvoted your post later removed that vote.

A user can retract or change a vote (up or down) for a short period after they cast it. However if the post is later edited, then they can retract or change their vote again. This allows you to upvote a previously bad answer if it's now good, or downvote a previously good answer if it's now bad.

Comment: Is there any other ways that it can be done or can it only be done by the original voter? Is there a permission level were one is granted the ability to change the votes place by others?

Comment: No other user can change your votes.